# Will a firebase https url receive http post requests?

Tags: firebase, http, post, https, google-cloud-functions

I've read that Firebase only receive post/get requests if it is in HTTPS. But then I tried HTTP post/get simulation such as POSTMAN and I can actually post data to firebase. Do you think Firebase receive HTTP or does POSTMAN automatically convert the request to HTTPS?

I use Firebase Functions to receive/send data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Functions accepts both HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443) requests.  That is expected.  You should only use HTTPS if you're concerned about security, and you should also check the scheme of the incoming request to make sure it's HTTPS, and reject HTTP.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up. I'm building a project with sim900 that sends only HTTP. I was just curious if I can connect it directly to firebase function without using rest. Thanks for the answer.